# How to get the number of elements in a firebase collection?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to get the sum of elements in my firebase collection so far ive tried doing

```
final int documents = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('stations').snapshots().length;
```

but when i print documents variable with a print statement i get this:

```
Instance of '_Future<int>'
```

What should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `snapshots` property is a stream, and you can't use `await` on that. Furthermore, you are now essentially awaiting the `length` property lookup, instead of the asynchronous call.

This should work better:

```
var docs = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('stations').get();
final int count = docs.size;
```

The main differences:

- This uses `get` instead of `snapshots` to get the documents.
- Since `get` returns a `Future`, it uses `await` on that call.

Comment: just changed .lenght with size and it works thanks buddy ! Please upvote so I can get rep.